# Ionic 2 MobileFirst 8 handleChallenge function not called

Tags: ionic2, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to call handleChallenge worklight methods in Mobilefirst 8.0. But is not called

```
AuthInit() {
    this.challengeHandler = 
    WL.Client.createSecurityCheckChallengeHandler("UserLogin");
    this.challengeHandler.handleChallenge = ((challenge) => {
      console.log('---> inside handleChallenge');
    });
}
```

And i have called a protected resource ( adapter methods )

```
getPosts() {
    var resourceRequest = new 
     WLResourceRequest("/adapters/AppDataAdapter/posts", 
           WLResourceRequest.GET);

    resourceRequest.send().then({
      console.log(response);
    });
}
```

but handleChallenge not called

Comment: Is your resource adapter method's scope is mapped with Userlogin Security Check in MFP Console Security Configurations tab ??

Comment: Verify using client side logs or Wireshark if server is sending a challenge to your application

Comment: Yes i have mapped the scope with UserLogin in MFP console